# Why du or echo pipelining is not working?

Tags: linux, echo, pipeline, du

I'm trying to use du command for every directory in the current one. So I'm trying to use code like this:

```
ls | du -sb
```

But its not working as expected. It outputs only size of current '.' directory and thats all.
The same thing is with echo

```
ls | echo
```

Outputs empty line. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using a pipe sends the output (*stdout*) of the first command, to *stdin* (input) of the child process (2nd command). The commands you mentioned don't take any input on `stdin`. This would work, for example, with `cat` (and by work, I mean work like `cat` run with no arguments, and just pass along the input you give it):

```
ls | cat
```

For your applications, this is where `xargs` comes in. It takes piped input and gives it as arguments to the command specified. So, you can make it work like:

```
ls | xargs du -sb
```

Beware that by default `xargs` will break its input on spaces, so if your filenames contain spaces this won't work as you want. So, in this particular case, this would be better:

```
du -sb *
```

Comment: The `*` is a glob (or wildcard as you may know it). The shell will replace it with all the file (or directory, etc) names in the current directory that match it.  Y could also, for instance, say `*.jpg` to match any file ending with .jpg

Answer (score 5):

Use command substitution, like this:

```
du -sb $(ls -d */)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec du -sb {} \;
```

or

```
$ ls -d */ | xargs du -sb
```